# Review notification with no reviews

Tags: bug

There is a sign on the top that says there are 4 items in the review queue for me but when I look at [the review queue](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/review) there is none.

This issue has been going on for a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is a known consequence of the design of this feature, and the StackExchange team has indicated that they do not plan to fix it.  The issue is that they cache this number, and the cache gets out of date.  Also, they compute the total number of reviews, rather than the number that you personally can perform, because they don't want to compute it separately for each user, which can also cause the number to be inflated.  Computing the correct number for each user would be too computationally expensive, apparently.

So, in summary: known defect, no plan to fix it.

See [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/160917) and [Modulate the review notification's color to reflect changes, or make it dismissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230833/160917).

Comment: I see. It's a bit strange since they do compute it when we visit the reveiw page.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the same problem, but not on cstheory. On academia.SE, where I'm not a mod, I've had 3 phantom items in my review queue for a while now.

Comment: It seems someone cleared up mine. But now it does not show a notification even when there is something in the review queue.